# Application's data folder in Mac

Tags: macos, updates, special-folders

What is the equivalent of Window's `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\appName`?

I need a directory that won't cause permission problems to store the updateable part 
of my application so I can automatically download and override my content.

Thank you.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/
```

**Edit:**

This answer has drawn a lot of upvotes despite its minimalistic nature. Therefore, I want to point out the things mentioned in the comments here to make them more visible:

- There are several other folders being used for application data / configuration, as mentioned in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28928/what-is-the-osx-equivalent-to-windows-appdata-folder/28930#28930).
- If writing an application, don't hardcode that path. Instead, use macOS' API to retrieve it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430777/programmatically-get-path-to-application-support-folder) has several answers for both ObjectiveC and Swift.

Comment: One shouldn't actually hard-code that path, since it is possible to move one's home directory.   Use `-[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory: NSApplicationSupportDirectory  inDomains: NSUserDomainMask].`

Comment: **This may not be the correct answer**. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28930/6533

Comment: On my Mac `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` (C#) returns `/Users/USERNAME/.config`, which (probably as a result) is also a folder that is used by some applications.

Comment: @JoostHuizinga Yes, that directory conforms to the [XDG Directory Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). This schema is primarily used by applications that have been ported from Linux; however, it is not considered by macOS to be a config directory. Note that this directory is sometimes also used on Windows by ported applications; so it is certainly not equivalent to Windows' *native* application data directory.

Comment: Is there an environment variable for that?

Comment: @Royi Not directly, but you can use `"$HOME/Library/Application Support"` in a script.

Answer (score 20):

```
~/Library/Application Support/
```

in shift+command+G in finder

Comment: Thanks for adding the keyboard shortcut, very helpful.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Is there an environment variable for that?